# A matrix inequality

Tags: matrix-analysis, linear-matrix-inequalities

Suppose we have three semi-definite positive matrices $A,B,C$ with $A+B=I$.

Do we have the following inequality
$$
Tr[(CAC)^{1+s}B]\leq Tr [(CBC)^s CAC]
$$
holds for any $0<s<1$?

This is true for commuting $A,B,C$.

Comment: My computer calculations (using gradient ascent) indicate a stronger inequality $$\text{Tr}[(CAC)^{1+s}B]\leq\text{Tr}[(CBC)^s CAC]\cdot s^s(1-s)^{1-s}.$$

Comment: By setting $X=CAC,Y=CBC$, we can rewrite the stronger inequality as $$\text{Tr}[X^{1+s}C^{-1}YC^{-1}]\leq\text{Tr}[XY^s]s^s(1-s)^{1-s}$$ where $C=\sqrt{X+Y}$. Here $X,Y$ are arbitrary positive semidefinite matrices with $X+Y$ invertible.

Comment: Thanks! That is the original question.

Comment: My computer calculations indicate that if $\lambda_1\leq\dots\leq\lambda_d$ are the eigenvalues of $X^{1+s}C^{-1}YC^{-1}$ and $\mu_1\leq\dots\leq\mu_d$ are the eigenvalues of $XY^ss^s(1-s)^{1-s}$, then $\lambda_j\leq\mu_j$ whenever $1\leq j\leq d$.

Comment: Can you find a nice expression in terms of $X,Y$ for a unitary matrix $U(X,Y)$ where $$U(X,Y)X^{1/2}Y^sX^{1/2}s^s(1-s)^{1-s}U(X,Y)^*- Y^{1/2}C^{-1}X^{1+s}C^{-1}Y^{1/2}$$ is always positive semidefinite (or something similar to that)?

Comment: That is a very nice and strong suggestion. I have no idea yet. But it is worth trying.